# How do write IF ELSE statement in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, if-statement

How do I write an IF ELSE statement in a MySQL query?

Something like this:

```
mysql_query("...(irrelevant code).. IF(action==2&&state==0){state=1}");
```

Then down in my array I should be able to do this:

```
 $row['state'] 
//this should equal 1, the query should not change anything in the database, 
//just the variable for returning the information
```

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You probably want to use a [`CASE` expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case).

They look like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, (case when (action = 2 and state = 0) 
 THEN
      1 
 ELSE
      0 
 END)
 as state from tbl1;
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer seemed the easier to follow, (as far as where the case is suppose to go in the query, however I have been unable to get it to work properly:

"SELECT *, N.id (CASE WHEN (N.action == 2 AND N.state == 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS N.state FROM notifications N, posts P WHERE N.userID='$session' AND N.uniqueID=P.id AND P.state='0' AND N.action='1' ORDER BY N.date DESC"

Comment: @DylanCross Looks like you might be missing a comma between `N.id` and `(CASE WHEN ...`

Comment: Ahh, didn't see that, but even when i put the comma it doesn't work.

Comment: @DylanCross You might also need to change `AS N.state` to `AS state`.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== 2 AND N.state == 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS state FROM notifications N, posts P' at line 1

Comment: @DylanCross Doesn't MySQL use `=` instead of `==` for comparison?

Comment: Yes, I had just changed those and it seems to be working, well as far as not returning an error, I think all I have to do now is just play around with the query, as it's sort of a complex thing I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks with your help regarding my question.

Comment: how about for other case ?

Answer (score 34):

you must write it in SQL not it C/PHP style

```
IF( action = 2 AND state = 0, 1, 0 ) AS state
```

for use in query

```
IF ( action = 2 AND state = 0 ) THEN SET state = 1
```

for use in stored procedures or functions

Comment: I am unable to get this to work with my code, perhaps my placement is wrong, or something:

SELECT *, N.id IF( N.action = 2 AND N.state = 0, 1, 0 ) AS N.state FROM notifications N, posts P WHERE N.userID='$session' AND N.uniqueID=P.id AND P.state='0' AND N.action='1' ORDER BY N.date DESC

Answer (score 19):

You're looking for `case`:

```
case when action = 2 and state = 0 then 1 else 0 end as state
```

MySQL has an `if` syntax (`if(action=2 and state=0, 1, 0)`), but `case` is more universal.

Note that the `as state` there is just aliasing the column. I'm assuming this is in the column list of your SQL query.

Comment: This is a much better answer

Answer (score 17):

```
SELECT col1, col2, IF( action = 2 AND state = 0, 1, 0 ) AS state from tbl1;
```

OR

```
SELECT col1, col2, (case when (action = 2 and state = 0) then 1 else 0 end) as state from tbl1;
```

both results will same....

Comment: one thing I noticed but couldn't find documentation on it is that the IF has to be the last in the list of columns. If it is first, then it gives an error. Anyone know where to see this in the documentation? Its driving me crazy. WHen I discover something, I like to see it documented for future reference

Answer (score 8):

according to the mySQL reference manual  this the syntax of using if and else statement :

> ```
> IF search_condition THEN statement_list
> [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
> [ELSE statement_list]
> END IF
> ```

So regarding your query :

```
x = IF((action=2)&&(state=0),1,2);
```

or you can use

```
IF ((action=2)&&(state=0)) then 
state = 1;
ELSE 
state = 2;
END IF;
```

There is good example in this link : 
http://easysolutionweb.com/sql-pl-sql/how-to-use-if-and-else-in-mysql/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: also make sure your example works.  otherwise, you're just wasting people's time.