# How to use if/else in an UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql

Here is my current query

```
UPDATE `records` SET tester1 = '$user', tester1yn = '$pass'
```

What I would like to change this to is

```
UPDATE `records` SET
IF `tester1` IS NULL `tester1` = $user, AND `test1` = $pass
ELSE `tester2` = $user, `tester1yn` = '$pass'
WHERE `id` = $id
```

But as I have it this does not work. Am I having a nested issue, or I am going about this the wrong way?

UPDATE BASED ON FEEDBACK

```
UDPATE records SET 
tester1 = if(tester1 IS NULL,'$user',tester1), 
tester1yn = if(tester1 is null, '$pass', tester1yn), 
tester2 = IF(tester1 is not null, '$user', tester2), 
tester2yn = IF(tester1 is not null,'$pass', tester2yn) 
where id = $id
```

still not there yet though.

Comment: Programming by _guessing_ does not work. Read the MySQL documentation to find out what its features are. Note that queries are single declarative statements, not procedural functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL IF ELSE statement in query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763310/mysql-if-else-statement-in-query)

Comment: This is a classic example of MySQL Injection, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: See [`CASE` (expression)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) in the MySQL documentation (hint: use the result of the expression). Then read up on [avoiding SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: I don't have any fear about MySQL injection. The whole project is a really dirty hack to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're kind of heading in the wrong direction, though this logic should be in the next layout out (in my opinion)

Try:

```
UPDATE records 
SET
tester1 = if(tester1 IS NULL,$user,tester1),
tester1yn = IF(tester1 IS NULL,$pass,tester1yn),
tester2 = IF(tester1 IS NOT NULL, $user,tester2),
tester2yn = IF(tester1 IS NOT NULL,'$pass',tester2yn)
WHERE id = $id";
```

Comment: Updated to this put still not working. i add "'" around all my php vars starting wtih $

Comment: had to switch the order of the tests to make it work correct.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test this, so don't hold me to it, but this should point you in the right direction:

```
UPDATE records 
SET 
    tester1 = CASE WHEN tester1 IS NULL THEN '$user' ELSE tester1 END,
    test1 = CASE WHEN tester1 IS NULL THEN '$pass' ELSE test1 END,
    tester2 = CASE WHEN tester1 IS NOT NULL THEN '$user' ELSE tester2 END,
    tester2yn = CASE WHEN tester1 IS NOT NULL THEN '$pass' ELSE tester2yn END
WHERE
    id = $id
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is doable in SQL, that sort of logic shouldn't be happening at the database level. The login, authentication and management of users (which seems to be what you're after) should be done in your code.