# MySQL Convering string to integer within the Query for Sphinx Filter

Tags: mysql, filter, sphinx

Sphinx cannot filter on strings, on integers.

I have some fields that are simple yes and no strings I would like to filter.

Is it possible to do a MySQL query something like this?

```
SELECT integer(FIELD:yes,1;no,2) AS sound FROM my_table;
```

Something like that?  So that instead of yes, it gives me 1 and instead of no it gives me 2?

Then I would have as an attribute:

```
 sql_attr_unit = sound
```

and I could filter like so:

```
 $c->SetFilter(sound, array(1));
```

Does this look right?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that an If Else solution is what is needed to use from this post:

[How do write IF ELSE statement in a MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763310/how-do-write-if-else-statement-in-a-mysql-query)

```
 SELECT (case when (Sound = 'yes') then 1 else 0 end) AS Sound FROM my_table;
```

This appears to be the solution for yes and no items.

Comment: Just a reference a short hand syntax: `SELECT IF(Sound='yes',1,0) AS Sound FROM ...`

Comment: @barryhunter I was actually hoping you would comment on this.  It doesn't seem to be working for me.  Can you check my modifications above and verify that it *should* work based on that so I can at least know it *should* work?  Thanks!!

Comment: For a real live and working example, http://svn.geograph.org.uk/svn/branches/british-isles/system/sphinxserver/usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf (search for 'prefered')

Comment: That's a great example @barryhunter.  Thanks for sharing that.  I think it will prove very useful.