# codeigniter: how to transform/convert numbers data to text from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

for example, i have a table like this

```
 book   |  number data  |
-------------------------
 book 1 |       2       |
 book 2 |       3       |
 book 3 |       1       |
 book 4 |       3       |
```

every number has a **name/value**:

`Good` for `1`

`Okay` for `2`

`Bad` for `3`

how to transform the numbers and displays them in the form of text? without changing the original data

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763310/how-do-write-if-else-statement-in-a-mysql-query

Comment: `$data = array(1 => 'Good', 2 => 'Okay', ...) echo $data[$row['number_data']]`?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array to get status

```
$output = Array(1=>"Good",2=>"Okay",3=>"Bad");
echo $output[$numberDate];
```

OR

Use `switch case` like this:

```
$output = ""
switch ($numberDate) {
case 1:
    $output = "Good";
    break;
case 2:
    $output = "Okay";
    break;
case 3:
    $output = "Bad";
    break;
}

echo $output;
```

Comment: you saved my life sir jajaja @saqiahmad

Answer (score -1):

```
 if ($number == 1) {
    echo "Good";
} elseif ($number == 2) {
  echo "Okay";
} else {
   echo "Bad";
}
```

Don't use a switch statement, they tend to be slower.

Comment: Please read this for performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158759/case-vs-if-else-if-which-is-more-efficient, always add references when you try do a statement for performance

Comment: In my experience, switch statements tend to run slower.