# Else if condition using mysql CASE not working?

Tags: php, mysql, case

I have column **location** but i need to return this column based on value of another column
below is the MYSQL SELECT QUERY:

```
if(block.block_id IS NOT NULL)
{
 location.location = 'BLOCKED'
}elseif(nvocc.nvocc_id is not null AND nvocc.nvocc_status = 'IN') {
  location.location = 'NVOCC'
}else {
  location.location = location.location
}
```

i treid with case conditon but its showing error

```
CASE 
     WHEN block.block_id IS NOT NULL THEN "BLOCKED"
     WHEN ((nvocc.nvocc_id IS NOT NULL) AND (nvocc.nvocc_status='IN')) THEN "NVOCC"
     ELSE location.location
END as location
```

the above query returns nothing and not working
please someone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What about you look at the [mySql tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do write IF ELSE statement in a MySQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763310/how-do-write-if-else-statement-in-a-mysql-query)

Comment: A query in MySQL starts with `SELECT`, not with `CASE`.  It is entirely unclear what code you are actually running.

Answer (score 1):

Try using parenthesis to clearly separate your condition block from control flow block:

```
CASE 
     WHEN block.block_id IS NOT NULL THEN "BLOCKED"
     WHEN ((nvocc.nvocc_id IS NOT NULL) AND (nvocc.nvocc_status='IN')) THEN "NVOCC"
     ELSE location.location
END
```

Try simplifying your query until it works and then progressively add conditions.

And please provide your error, it's really hard to guess.

Comment: Query is excuted but i there is no change in output

Comment: please provide the full request, it is hard to know else.