# how to implement IF ELSE statement in my sql select

Tags: mysql

kindly assist me on how to implement the code below since am getting this error

> " Incorrect syntax near '{'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.
>   Incorrect syntax near '}'"

```
      IF 
      TreatmentGroup=ALL
      {
      SELECT
      TreatmentItems.TreatmentGroup As TreatmentGroup,
      MedicalSchemeDetail.*
      FROM
      MedicalSchemeDetail JOIN TreatmentItems ON
      MedicalSchemeDetail.CompanyID = TreatmentItems.CompanyID AND 
      MedicalSchemeDetail.BranchID = TreatmentItems.BranchID AND 
      MedicalSchemeDetail.DepartmentID = TreatmentItems.DepartmentID AND
      MedicalSchemeDetail.ItemID = TreatmentItems.TreatmentID 
      WHERE
      AND MedicalSchemeDetail.CompanyID = @CompanyID 
      AND MedicalSchemeDetail.BranchID = @BranchID 
      AND MedicalSchemeDetail.DepartmentID = @DepartmentID 
      AND MedicalSchemeDetail.MedicalSchemeID = @MedicalSchemeID 
      AND IsNull(MedicalSchemeDetail.Excluded,0) = 0
      }
      ELSE
      {
      SELECT
      TreatmentItems.TreatmentGroup As TreatmentGroup,
      MedicalSchemeDetail.*
      FROM
      MedicalSchemeDetail JOIN TreatmentItems ON
      MedicalSchemeDetail.CompanyID = TreatmentItems.CompanyID AND 
      MedicalSchemeDetail.BranchID = TreatmentItems.BranchID AND 
      MedicalSchemeDetail.DepartmentID = TreatmentItems.DepartmentID AND
      MedicalSchemeDetail.ItemID = TreatmentItems.TreatmentID 
      WHERE
      TreatmentGroup=@TreatmentGroup
      AND MedicalSchemeDetail.CompanyID = @CompanyID 
      AND MedicalSchemeDetail.BranchID = @BranchID 
      AND MedicalSchemeDetail.DepartmentID = @DepartmentID 
      AND MedicalSchemeDetail.MedicalSchemeID = @MedicalSchemeID 
      AND IsNull(MedicalSchemeDetail.Excluded,0) = 0
      }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do write IF ELSE statement in a MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763310/how-do-write-if-else-statement-in-a-mysql-query)

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `AND` after the first `WHERE` In Query

Comment: thanks Feras, i have done that but am now getting this error.. Incorrect syntax near '{'. Incorrect syntax near '}'. Incorrect syntax near '}'.   kindly just edit for me