# How to apply case in where clause in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query in SQL Server with the following `where` condition

```
where  (Convert(date,AppDate) between Convert(date,''+@DateFrom +'') AND
    Convert(date,''+@DateTo+'') and DrCode =  '' +@DrCode+'' )
```

But I want to add  `and DrCode =  '' +@DrCode+''` when DrCode>0

How to set it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do write IF ELSE statement in a MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763310/how-do-write-if-else-statement-in-a-mysql-query)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are doing string concatenations like this:

```
'' + @DateFrom + ''
```

In any case, I don't think a `CASE` expression is appropriate for what you want to do.  Just spell out the logic directly in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
    CONVERT(date, AppDate) BETWEEN
        CONVERT(date, @DateFrom) AND CONVERT(date, @DateTo) AND
        ((DrCode = @DrCode AND DrCode > 0) OR DrCode <= 0);
```

Comment: The double single quotes make me think the code in the question is a snippet from a dynamic SQL string. Just a hunch, though.

Comment: @EricBrandt That might explain it.  Anyway, I don't think that would change the logic I am presenting one way or the other.

Comment: I agree. The logic holds up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `DrCode > 0` condition with `DrCode =  '' +@DrCode+''`  separately then you can try the following:

```
where (Convert(date,AppDate) between Convert(date,''+@DateFrom +'') AND
    Convert(date,''+@DateTo+'')) and 
    (CASE WHEN DrCode > 0 AND DrCode =  '' +@DrCode+'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END =1)
```