# SQL: return true/false if a related record is presented

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

```
ASSIGNMENTS (ID)
ASSIGNMENT_REVIEWS (ID, ASSIGNMENT_ID)
```

As a result of selecting I'd like to retrieve a flag if a review is already presented for the assignment. How to do it in the best way?

Comment: spend some time to study :), so to flag it, you need some true/false - a hint for you is you could you 1/0 to represent true/false. 2nd hint, it's a condition, so think about if / else, and assume you are using mysql, use CASE expression: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763310/how-do-write-if-else-statement-in-a-mysql-query

Comment: @Jacky: There's no reason why one should *"assume you are using mysql"* when the question is clearly tagged as Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the exists statement:

```
select 
    id,
    case when exists (
        select 1 from assignment_reviews where assignment_reviews.assignment_id = assignments.id
    ) then 1 else 0 end as hasReview
from
    assignments
```

Comment: This isn't even a [valid syntax](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5283ec91d1eddc9082ecf40083dd5ac4) in Oracle. I'm not sure how was it accepted and even got 2 upvotes.

Comment: It is now. Thank you for pointing out mistakes with so much politeness and respect to other. I wish more people could be like you.

Comment: No @KaushikNayak it works. Please refer : [Q56061620](https://rextester.com/XFUHI98521)

Comment: @KaushikNayak oh, I didn't notice, excuse me, you're right :).

Answer (score 1):

> You can use a `left join` with `nvl2()` function(*returns the
>   value in the `2nd argument` if the 1st argument is `not null`, `otherwise`
>   returns the `3rd argument` practically* )

```
with assignments(id) as
(
 select 101 from dual union all
 select 102 from dual
), assignments_reviews(id,assignment_id) as
(
 select 855, 101 from dual 
)
select a.id, 
       nvl2(r.assignment_id,1,0) as already_presented
  from assignments a
  left join assignments_reviews r
    on r.assignment_id = a.id;

ID  ALREADY_PRESENTED
101 1
102 0
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/QZIND52846)</kbd>